# Failed to parse the output of adb version? MAC

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, adt

I have used Android ADT bundle in Windows 7. There is no issue.

But when I try to use Android ADT bundle in MAC, I'm getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
```

And

```
Failed to parse the output of "adb version".
```

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8, JDK 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform for `adt-bundle-mac-x86_64.zip` is Mac OS X 64-bit, so it seems there is no 32-bit Mac version. We can still download Eclipse and then add ADT manually though.

Answer (score 0):

Make visible java for android sdk

$sudo ln -s /home/azware/tmp/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/java /usr/bin/java